# confused when to use addslashes and when to use htmlentities

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Htmlentities vs addslashes vs mysqli_real_escape_string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2214244/htmlentities-vs-addslashes-vs-mysqli-real-escape-string)
>   [When to use which string escaping method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5770912/when-to-use-which-string-escaping-method)

Hi,
    I get very confused when to use addslashes and when to use htmlentities.

can you please tell me a example where in i should use addslashes and when to use htmlentities.

Comment: Maybe add some more context - what are you trying to do?

Comment: @Pekka - i fetch data from DB and try to show it in a text box...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Never use addslashes.
- Also never use `htmlentities()`<sup>*</sup>
- Use `htmlspecialchars()` when outputting untrusted content in the context of a HTML page.

In general, there is usually one correct method of escaping/sanitizing your data, depending on what you want to do with it. If you tell us more about what you are trying to do, somebody will be able to point you into the right direction.

<sub><sup>*</sup> = unless you need it, which is usually never. `htmlentities()` turns many more characters than necessary into their respective HTML entities, which has become largely superfluous in the days of UTF-8. For security, the range of characters covered by `htmlspecialchars()` is enough.</sub>

Comment: Almost word for word what I was about to type. +1 (Although I'd say to only use `htmlentities` when outputting to an environment where you can't control the character encoding http headers. `htmlspecialchars` is usually a better choice)

Comment: Good choice wikifying this one Pekka :) You answer leaves much to debate and doesn't explain anything to OP. I seem to remember a recent debate about how htmlentities should never be used when htmlspecialchars is available. Should be noted that OP most likely needs a means of escaping data, which is why he's asking about addslashes. Maybe telling him how to escape without addslashes would help.

Comment: @Wesley yeah, I already fixed the `entities()` thing. (I wikified it because it's such a blatant duplicate, not out of fear of downvotes) @David yeah, fixed to recommend htmlspecialchars().

Comment: @pekka - so you mean to say that while outputting data i must use htmlentities/ htmlspecialchars.   and i should use addslashes when making data safe for DB rite ..... does addslashes have no part to play in front end ???

Comment: @pradeep never use addslashes to make data safe for the database: Always use the sanitation method offered by your database library (like `mysql_real_escape_string()`), or parametrized queries. To output data in a text box, `htmlspecialchars()` is enough.

Comment: @pekka - so i am confused when should i use addslashes  function ideally

Comment: @pradeep only in very specialized cases like when injecting JavaScript code into a HTML tag's  `onclick=""` event for example. Quotes inside the JavaScript code need to be escaped so they don't break the HTML. Never use it to sanitize data for the database.

Answer (score 2):

It's slightly confusing, I agree. But, let's see if we can help :)

`htmlentities` makes data safe for outputting into an HTML document. The PHP manual says.

> This function is identical to htmlspecialchars() in all ways, except with htmlentities(), all characters which have HTML character entity equivalents are translated into these entities.

But keep in mind that using htmlentities() in an UTF-8 encoded document should be avoided at all costs! There are always problems, see http://www.phpwact.org/php/i18n/charsets#common_problem_areas_with_utf-8

`addslashes` makes data safe for a few other situations, but if your database has its own then use that, for MySQL (`mysql_real_escape_string` is needed there)

Comment: Bound parameters are a much better option than `mysql_real_escape_string`

Comment: so you mean to say that while outputting data i must use htmlentities/ htmlspecialchars.   and i should use addslashes when making data safe for DB rite ..... does addslashes have no part to play in front end ???

Comment: I've never really used `addslashes` on front end things, so I wouldn't worry too much.